# Finding Rational Root of Polynomial in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy, floating-accuracy

I am having a little issue regarding  solving polynomial in python's `sympy.solvers`. What I want is to find the rational root, not irrational root. my attempt is given below -

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
from fractions import Fraction

b_2=0
b_4= -10
b_6=32
b_8=-25

x_2p=-7/4

x = Symbol('x', real=True)
solution=solve(((4*x**3+b_2*x**2+2*b_4*x+b_6)*x_2p-(x**4-b_4*x**2-2*b_6*x-b_8)), x)
R=solution
if len(R) != 0:
    print(Fraction(R[1]))
```

I got below error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Roy\Desktop\EXP_2704 - Copy.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(Fraction(R[1]))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\fractions.py", line 161, in __new__
    raise TypeError("argument should be a string "
TypeError: argument should be a string or a Rational instance
```

Note that I need to get accurate fraction from floating.

How can I find  rational root?

Comment: You gave up all hope of an exact answer the moment you wrote `-7/4`, which produces a floating-point value.  It's a float that happens to be an exact representation of the value, but sympy has no way of knowing that - so it gives up on trying to give you an exact symbolic result, and just calculates floats.  (And it's fundamentally impossible to tell whether a float is supposed to represent a rational or irrational value.)

Comment: @jasonharper but the problem is not happening at `x_2p=-7/4` but at `print(Fraction(R[1]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `real_roots` you will get a CRootOf instance that can be computed with arbitrary precision. Using your initialization and the following I get:

```
>>> from sympy import Rational, real_roots
>>> eq = ((4*x**3+b_2*x**2+2*b_4*x+b_6)*x_2p-(x**4-b_4*x**2-2*b_6*x-b_8)); eq
-x**4 - 7.0*x**3 - 10*x**2 + 99.0*x - 81.0
>>> real_roots(_)
[1, CRootOf(x**3 + 8*x**2 + 18*x - 81, 0)]
>>> r=_[1]
>>> Rational(r.n(2))
133/64
>>> Rational(r.n(20))
613677434358103191805/295147905179352825856
```

Comment: why we need `eq -x**4 - 7.0*x**3 - 10*x**2 + 99.0*x - 81.0`  ..... could you plz provide complete code according to my my code?

Comment: I just defined `eq` to be your argument to `solve` and then I showed you what it looks like. And then I used `real_roots` instead of `solve`. In your code replace `solve` with `real_roots` and leave of `, x`...you will get the list of solutions that I show in the answer.